# How to create a button to change a text in my html with data coming from Django's models.py?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm starting to work with Django and I'm starting a test to solidify what I've been learning. The idea is a single page, which displays a sentence as soon as the site opens. Below the phrase, there is a button that I would like to change the phrase to some other phrase coming from a variable declared in models.py and which contains several phrases that were registered through Django's admin panel.

This is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models


class Base(models.Model):
    criado = models.DateField('Criado', auto_now_add=True)
    modificado = models.DateField('Atualização', auto_now=True)
    ativo = models.BooleanField('Ativo', default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Frase(Base):
    frase = models.CharField('Frase', max_length=100)
    dica = models.CharField('Dica', max_length=200, default='-')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Frase'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Frases'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.frase
```

This is my views.py file:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import Frase


class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['frases'] = Frase.objects.order_by('?').all()

        return context
```

This is my index.html

```
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 h-100">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 align-self-end">
                        <h1 class="text-white font-weight-bold" id="frase">{{ frases|first }}</h1>
                        <hr class="divider" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8 align-self-baseline">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" onclick="nova_frase()">Nova frase</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     (...) <!--rest of the html code-->
        
         <script type="text/javascript">
            function nova_frase() {
                document.getElementById('frase').innerText = 'a';
            }
        </script>
```

"document.getElementById('phrase').innerText = 'a';" was my last test to try to create some change to the page through the button.
I tried using .innerHTML, but with no success either.

I'm having difficulties finding texts to do this task (click the button and change the phrase being displayed by another phrase coming from the variable defined in models.py).

I'm using Python 3.9.5 and Django 3.2.5.

If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly change the text based on the frontend javascript event. First send all the buttons from Django to frontend template and store it in the javascript list. Then, use the javascript to display it based on the changes.

The another approach would be using Ajax.